# How does init function works?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why does `console.log("init2");` gets printed before `console.log("init1");` ? And when I execute `console.log(categories);` inside subscribe I get the correct array in the console but when `console.log(this.categories);` is executed outside subscribe I don't get the array in the console instead the output is undefined. Why? How should I correct it?

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/modules/common/services/category.service';
import { CourseService } from '../../services/course.service';
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  categories: any[];
  courses: any[];
  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private categoryService : CategoryService, private courseService : CourseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.categoryService.getAllcategories()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(categories => this.courseService.getAllCourses().pipe(
        map(courses => [categories, courses])
      ))).subscribe(([categories, courses]) => {
        this.categories = categories;
        this.courses = courses;
        console.log("init1");
        console.log(categories);
      });
      console.log("init2");
      console.log(this.categories);

  }

  getCoursesByCategory(key: any)
  {
      //console.log(key);
      return this.courses.filter(course => course.category == key)
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an function that returns an observable, which is the case with your `getAllCourses` the call is asynchronous. So if the call is very fast you could get init1 displayed before init2 or not. So the behavior and the code are OK.

You should have a look here to better understand how it all works: https://angular.io/guide/observables